# 2.8 how to move 3d curser like a normal object?

Tags: 3d-cursor

i really like that for moving a object i just press G and then x to snap the movement to the X axisis. i use this feature all the time and would like to be able to simply move the 3d curser along an axisis. drag and drop and by numbers would both be great.

i want to be able to quickly but precisely set the pivot point like that.
the closet i can come to this is create a single dot ... move it where i want it and set 3d curser to selection. is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cursor tool on your toolbar, drag it and then press x,y or z to move it along an axis.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i don't know how to do that. what am i supposed to drag? the 3d curser is not draggable

Comment: In the tool bar on left side, there is the cursor icon below the selection tool. Select that, and then you can drag the cursor when you leftclick it in the viewport. (No transformation gadget will shop up though) If you press x,y,z while draging it, it will move along the specific axis.